# I am creating a desktop application c#. Net how can create a file at client to use this application

Tags: c#

I build a c# windows form application to execute warehouse operation and I want to use it at multiple clients without see the source code of my application
how can create a file or any think at client to use my c#. Net application

Try to create file at client

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Is your client not able to install and run your application for some reason?  What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an installer package (setup.exe) or a deployment package (.msi file) that clients can run to install your application on their machines. If you use Visual Studio just click "Publish" in your navigation panel. There you have everything you need.